# How to deploy translation

Tags: deployment, translation

There are translations of some field labels and picklist value in sandbox.
How can I deploy these translation to production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170698&type=1) says

> In order for translated terms to be migrated via change set, both the
>   language translation and the component being translated must be
>   included in the change set.  For example, if you are migrating a
>   custom field label translation, the custom field must be in the change
>   set.
>
> When the translated components cannot be included in a change set
>   (such as custom picklist values for a standard field), these items
>   must be translated using a translation export/import.

Comment: Thanks Mahmood! I deployed the related fields first then deploy the language translation.But I can't found the fields were translated.Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Create a changeset, in which you must include both the language translation and the component. Then deploy that changeset in the target org.